# Php multiplication table for specified number

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a task to create a script which will output multiplication table just for specified number. To create regular multiplication table, for example 10x10 we would write something like this:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";

        for ($r =0; $r < $rows; $r++){

            echo'<tr>';

            for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++)
                echo '<td>' .$c*$r.'</td>';
           echo '</tr>'; // close tr tag here

        }

  echo"</table>";
```

But output which i am supposed to receive, for example for digit "3", should look like this:

```
|1 x 1 = 1|1 x 2 = 2|1 x 3 = 3|
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|2 x 1 = 2|2 x 2 = 4|2 x 3 = 6|
|3 x 1 = 3|3 x 2 = 6|3 x 3 = 9|
```

Anyone got an idea how to echo this using php (while and/or for) loops?

Comment: can't you just add it inside the `echo`? a simple concatenation would work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to output the text of the calculation as well as the result, e.g. `1 x 3 = 3`. You're missing that from your output.

Also, you need to start your `for` loops at `1` rather than `0`, otherwise you get `0 x 0 = 0` which I assume you don't want. You would compensate for the loss of iterations by using `<=` instead of `<` in your condition of the `for` loop so you still get 3 iterations (in this example).

Try this:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($r = 1; $r <= $rows; $r++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($c = 1; $c <= $cols; $c++) {
        echo sprintf('<td>%d x %d = %d</td>', $r, $c, $c * $r);
    }
    echo '</tr>'; // close tr tag here
}
echo '</table>';
```

Your expected output also seems to suggest that the first row should be a heading. It would seem odd to me to do that, but if that *is* the case, you'll need to do this instead:

```
$cellType = ($r === 1) ? 'th' : 'td'; // use <th> for the first row, otherwise <td>
echo sprintf('<%s>%d x %d = %d</%s>', $cellType, $r, $c, $c * $r, $cellType);
```